# What conditions are required for running loop in parallel in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, loops, parallel-processing, requirements

I have such piece of code:

```
foreach (var elem in coll.AsParallel())
{
   ... // some *local* computation
   cache.Add(elem,computation_outcome);
}
```

where `cache` is `ConcurrentDictionary` and `Add` is extension method which wraps `TryAdd` and throws exception on failure.

It works. The only problem is, it does not run in parallel.

**Question** -- what are the requirements to run loop in parallel?

*I know about forcing parallel mode, but I am just asking about requirements for parallel execution.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsParallel()` is intended for LINQ queries. It will not make a normal `foreach()` run in parallel.

You should use something like:

```
Parallel.ForEach (coll, elem => 
{
   ... // some *local* computation
   cache.Add(elem,computation_outcome);
} );
```